# Calling feature file with multiple arguments

Tags: karate

I want to call a feature file with 3 arguments, 1 st argument to create entity with that name and rest of 2 arguments to verify created entity has desired values for particular fields.
How can I do this in Karate??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep all the input in one JSON and pass it to your feature as mentioned in this documentation.

[Calling other features](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files)

```
Feature: main 
 Scenario: 
  * def result = call read('myfeature.feature') { createEntity: 'value', arg1: 'arg1Value',arg2: 'arg2Value'}
```

Inside your called feature you can directly access the values by the key that you used in your JSON.